# Allocating space for pointers to struct

Tags: c, sizeof

In another post [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250675/contiguous-block-of-memory-with-malloc)

I am trying to do the same thing with a struct, but I have a problem with my sizeof operator, so in the integer case, I did this:

```
size_t totalMem = rows * sizeof(int *) + rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

And in the struct case I did this:

```
size_t totalMem = (rows * sizeof(struct TEST *)) + (rows * cols * sizeof(struct TEST));
```

But I get the error: Invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type of struct TEST.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're defining the struct as

```
 typedef struct { ... } TEST;
```

you should always refer to the struct as `TEST`, not `struct TEST`, i.e. use

```
 size_t totalMem = (rows * sizeof(TEST*)) + (rows * cols * sizeof(TEST));
```

To use `struct TEST` you need to actually name the struct, i.e.

```
 struct TEST { ... };
```

You can allow both with

```
 typedef struct TEST { ... } TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "C2_Assignment_5_Exercise_2_Driver.h"
```

as part of my size_t statement.  And then the definition in the .h file is:

```
#ifndef C2_ASSIGNMENT_5_EXERCISE_2_DRIVER_H
#define C2_ASSIGNMENT_5_EXERCISE_2_DRIVER_H

typedef struct
{
   char charObj;
   short shortObj;
   long longObj;
   double doubleObj;
} TEST;

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
typedef struct MYTEST
{
   char charObj;
   short shortObj;
   long longObj;
   double doubleObj;
} TEST;
```

and

```
size_t totalMem = (rows * sizeof(struct TEST *)) + (rows * cols * sizeof(struct TEST));
```

to

```
size_t totalMem = (rows * sizeof(struct MYTEST *)) + (rows * cols * sizeof(struct MYTEST));
```